# COPY AND PASTE FROM CLOSED WORKBOOK

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy range from '1ST FILE' file and paste into '2ND FILE'

Here is the code I used. Which when I run it will pop out file dialog to choose which workbook I want to open and copy it range data. The filedialog will ask for range and I will enter something like this `$b$200:$L$500`.

Then it will paste on  '2ND FILE' and here I need to fill out file dialog where to paste the data range .

My questions are;

1.What code I need to write to get the data range by only type like this `200:500` only. where $b and $l is fix column. I just want to enter `200:500` instead of enter this `$b$200:$L$500`

2.What code I need to write to get the data range  paste by default on ''`A5`'' cell on '2ND FILE' without fill in dialog box  "Select destination cell'

Here is the code I used

```
Private Sub importbr_Click()

Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook


xTitleId = "Select BR file"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate

        Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A5", Type:=8)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2


        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: you can use `Set xRng2 = xWb.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5")`

Comment: for the 1st part, you will have to get the input as string, split it by ":" and get the numbers separately. then you can use it in the code.

Comment: Or, for the first part, you can use input box twice. Once for start row, then for end row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub importbr_Click()

    Dim xAddWb As Workbook
    Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim addStartRow As Integer
    Dim addEndRow As Integer
    Dim xRng1 As Range

    xTitleId = "Select BR file"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Set xAddWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
            addStartRow = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Type start row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="200", Type:=1)
            addEndRow = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Type end row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="500", Type:=1)
            With xAddWb.Sheets(1) 'change the index as needed
                Set xRng1 = .Range(.Cells(addStartRow, 2), .Cells(addEndRow, 12))
            End With

            'alternative #1 'in case, we want the values in the WB, that has this code
            xRng1.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

            'alternative #2 'in case, we want the values in the active WB, the one on top, active window
            xRng1.Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

            'alternative #3 'in case, we want the values in the a WB, which is always the same
            Dim wbTarget As Workbook
            Set wbTarget = Workbooks("the name of target workbook is always the same")
            xRng1.Copy Destination:=wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")

            'alternative #4 'we let user select one cell in target workbook. Add some error handling!
            Dim targetRange As Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set targetRange = Application.InputBox("Select cell where to paste values", "Select target cell", Type:=8)
            If Not targetRange Is Nothing Then
                xRng1.Copy Destination:=targetRange
            Else
                MsgBox "The target range was not set properly.", vbExclamation, "Input error"
            End If

            xAddWb.Close False
        End If
    End With 'FileDialog

End Sub
```

Comment: After of few hour looking for solution, finally I come out with the solution. thanks a lot for your help @Branislav Kollár .

Comment: @NadalMir Glad to hear that. This was a lot of effort. Found one cool [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/) that may help you understand more.